# How to get a user by their ID

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I have a Whois/Userinfo command for my bot it works great until you cant use ID's for the command so you have to ping users and Im wondering how to make it so you can use ID's and pings

```
    const Discord = require('discord.js');

    module.exports = {
        name: 'whois',
        description: "Clear messages!",
       async  execute(client, message, args) {
            let user;
            if (message.mentions.users.first()) {
                user = message.mentions.users.first();
            } else {
                user = message.author;
            }
            
            const member = message.guild.member(user);
            
            const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
                .setColor("RANDOM")
                .setAuthor(`${user.tag}`, `${member.user.displayAvatarURL({ dynamic: true })}`,)
                .setThumbnail(`${member.user.displayAvatarURL({ dynamic: true })}`)
                .addField(`${user.tag}`, `${user}`, true)
                .addField("Joined The Server On:", `${member.joinedAt}`, true)
                
                .addField("Joined Discord At", member.user.createdAt)
    
                .addField("Nickname:", `${member.nickname !== null ? `${member.nickname}` : 'None'}`, true)
                .addField("Status:", user.presence.status, true)
                .addFields(
                    { name: 'User ID', value: `${user.id}` },
                    { name: 'Roles', value: member.roles.cache.map(role => role.toString()).join(' ')},
    
                    
                )
    
   
                
                .setFooter(`Replying to ${message.author.username}#${message.author.discriminator}`)
    
                message.channel.send(embed);
    
        }



   }
```

Answer (score 0):

We can check for multiple values while defining a certain variable. So we'd first want to check if there was a ping in the message, then if there wasn't check if the first argument can be turned into a user based on ID, and finally if there weren't any, get the message author:

```
const user = message.mentions.users.first() || client.users.cache.get(args[0]) || message.author
```